# Why is not my SPI communication working? (Atmega644)

Tags: c, microcontroller, spi, atmega

I'm building a drum machine, and I have stored a sample header file with a kick sound which takes values between 0 and 170. I want to send it over SPI to a 10-bit MCP4811 DAC which then outputs it to a 3.5mm audio jack.

I have my MISO,MOSI,SCK and RESET pins connected to my USB programmer as well as the DAC.

Here is a snippet of the audio file stored in "samples.h"

```
unsigned const char sample_1[2221] PROGMEM = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, ...}
unsigned int sample_len[1] = {2221}
```

So it is a sample of 2221 bits. This I want to send to the DAC using SPI with freq = 22 kHz.

I'm using a 16 MHz Crystal, so I set the fuses accordingly to use it.

I am using a Timer which overflows 22 kHz.

```
volatile unsigned int sample_count[1] = {0};
volatile unsigned int audio_out = 0;
volatile unsigned char spi_junk;

int main (void)
sei();
DDRB = 0b10110000; //Set MOSI, SCK and SS as output.
PORTB = (1 << PINB4) //active low on SS.

TIMSK1 = (1<<OCIE1A); //Enable interrupt
TCCR1B = (1<<WGM12) | (1<<CS11); // set CTC mode and divide clk by 8 
OCR1A = 91; //16 MHz/(8*91) ~ 22068 Hz

//SPI Init
SPCR = (1<<SPE) | (1<<MSTR);  //master, 8 MHz
SPSR = (1<<SPI2X);

ISR (TIMER1_COMPA_vect) {
    audio_out = 0;

//If play_track == 1, then the sound should be played back.
if (play_track && sample_count[0] < sample_len[0]){
   audio_out += (pgm_read_byte(&(sample_1[sample_count[0]++)));

// send audio_out to 10-bit DAC on SPI
PORTB &= ~(1<<PINB4); // B.4 (DAC /CS)
SPDR = (char) ((audio_out >> 6) & 0x000f); //byte 1 0 0 0 0 b9 b8 b7 b6
while (!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)));
spi_junk = SPDR;

SPDR = (char) ((audio_out & 0x003f) << 2); //byte 2 b5 b4 b3 b2 b1 b0 0 0
while (!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)));
spi_junk = SPDR;
PORTB |= (1<<PINB4);
}
```

My PIN set up is.

Atmega644 -> DAC

```
MOSI -> SDI

SCK -> SCK

SS -> /CS
```

On MCP4811

```
Vdd -> 5V

Vss -> GND

V_out -> Audio jack.
```

The rest of the pins on the MCP4811 are not connected to anything.

I have seen that the audio_out is working as expected, by displaying the audio_out value on a LCD screen. But nothing is being output to the DAC. Anyone see what could be wrong?

EDIT: Added the SPI init which I had missed to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line here

`SPDR = (char) ((audio_out >> 6) & 0x000f); //byte 1 0 0 0 0 b9 b8 b7 b6`

Will set ¬SHDN to 0 which will shutdown the DAC

`0 = Shutdown the device. Analog output is not available. VOUT pin is connected to 500 kohm typical)`

Set bit 12 to 1 instead

`SPDR = (char) ((audio_out >> 6) & 0x0f)|0x10; //byte 1 0 0 0 1 b9 b8 b7 b6`

from datasheet

`1 = Active mode operation. VOUT is available.`

Comment: Why would the SPDR set that? Can't I just connect the SHDN to the 5V rail instead?

Comment: The datasheet states ```The user can shut down the device using a software
command (<SHDN> = 0) or SHDN pin. During shutdown mode, most of the internal circuits, including the output amplifier, are turned off for power savings```

Comment: But that is not sent through the SPDR right? That is if I were to give the SHDN pin on the MCP4811 a designated pin on my MCU and set it to low?

Comment: See MCP4801/4811/4821 datasheet (DS22244B) page 22. ```"WRITE COMMAND REGISTER FOR MCP4811 (10-BIT DAC)"``` The ¬SHDN bit is sent as part of the ```WRITE REGISTER``` command.¬SHDN pin must be HIGH and ¬SHDN bit on DAC register must also be 1 otherwise there will be no analog output on Vout pin. ```The device will remain in Shutdown mode until the <SHDN> bit = 1 is latched into the device or SHDN pin is changed to logic high```. Please try first if this is the problem, as it may be not (its not difficult to change one bit)

Comment: This was the answer, in combination with setting SHDN to 5V rail. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no SPI initialization in your code.

add into `main()`

```
SPSR = (1 << SPI2X);  // double speed (to get maximum of 8MHz output)
SPCR = (1 << SPE)  | (1 << MSTR); // 1:1 prescaler, master mode, SPI mode 0, SPI enable
```

Also several remarks to your code:

use `sei()` only after all initializations are done, to avoid interrupts happened on uninitialized peripheral.

better first set PB4 high then setup it as output to avoid PB output low between two commands:

```
PORTB = (1 << PINB4) //active low on SS.
DDRB = 0b10110000; //Set MOSI, SCK and SS as output.
```

Comment: Thank you for noting that, unfortunately it was me who did a bad job of asking the question. I had these lines already. I also have SPCR = (1<<SPE) | (1<<MSTR) | (1<<CPOL);